# Determine How Many Times a Turtle Has Made a Dot in a Certain Location

Tags: python, if-statement, turtle-graphics

I am looking for a way so that every time a turtle makes a dot in a certain place, a counter variable will go up by one, but that variable only responds to a dot in that exact location, so there is effectively a record of how many times a turtle has made a dot in a specific location. Something like:

```
x=0
if (turtle.dot()):
       x+1
```

but obviously in this scenario, the count will increase for a dot of any position. Thanks in advance! C

Comment: No, just looking for a way to monitor the number of times a turtle has made a dot in a certain spot for a program I am writing.

Comment: Do you know the location of the spot?

Comment: No its supposed to be for ANY spot in general, any or every spot needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a`collections.defaultdict`to keep count the dots and derive your own `Turtle` subclass to help keep track of where the`dot{}`method is called. The key for the`defaultdict`will be the x and y coordinates of the turtle when `dot()` was called.

Here an example of what I mean:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from turtle import *

class MyTurtle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(MyTurtle, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)  # initialize base
        self.dots = defaultdict(int)

    def dot(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(MyTurtle, self).dot(*args, **kwds)
        self.dots[self.position()] += 1

    def print_count(self):
        """ print number of dots drawn, if any, at current position """
        print self.dots.get(self.position(), 0) # avoid creating counts of zero

def main(turtle):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.dot("blue")
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.dot("green")
    # go back to the start point
    turtle.right(180) # turn completely around
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.dot("red")  # put second one in same spot
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    turtle1 = MyTurtle()
    main(turtle1)
    mainloop()

    for posn, count in turtle1.dots.iteritems():
        print('({x:5.2f}, {y:5.2f}): '
              '{cnt:n}'.format(x=posn[0], y=posn[1], cnt=count))
```

Output:

```
(100.00, 50.00): 1
(100.00,  0.00): 2
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but is there also a way to express the current value for the position. So I could something like print(self.dots[self.position()])?

Comment: Yes, you could do something like that -- see the `print_count()` method I added in the update to my answer. When doing something like that you have to be careful not to add an entry to the `dots` dictionary when what you really want to do is just get a value from it if it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `turtle.pos()`, which returns Cartesian coordinates, to check the position of the turtle and consequently the dot?

```
if ((turtle.pos() == (thisX, thisY)) and turtle.dot()): 
    x+1
```

Comment: This would work very well, however, I need to use this for any possible dot. Is there a way to modify it so that that would be possible?

Comment: If it works with one it should work with any Cartesian 'spot' across the canvas. Just set 'thisX, thisY' to the coordinates you want to monitor.